# Does the order of the partial derivatives in a gradient vector matter?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Probably not a great question but I was thinking about how to apply multivariable calculus in real life and came up with a question.
If you have a multivariable  function with variables $x,y,z$ and a single output.
Does the order of the partial derivatives in the gradient matter? As in, are $(\partial x, \partial y, \partial z)$ and $(\partial z, \partial x, \partial y)$ the same? If not, then what are these differences?

Thank you,

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Of course it matters.

Comment: When you say "a multivariable function with variables $x$, $y$, $z$...," a mathematician implicitly orders the variables as listed. A different ordering of the variables already gives _a different function_. Does that clarify...?

Answer (score 0):

It matters, for example, the total derivative $T_{\mathbf a}$ at $\mathbf a$ can no longer be written as $\nabla f(\mathbf a)\cdot\mathbf v$. Some things stay same like the Laplacian $\nabla\cdot\nabla$ remains the same.

Point is, you want to write it in Cartesian coordinates using the basis vectors $(\mathbf{\hat x},\mathbf{\hat y},\mathbf{\hat z})\newcommand{\pdv}[2]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial #2}}$. You want to write
$$\nabla=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\mathbf{\hat x}+\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\mathbf{\hat y}+\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\mathbf{\hat z}\equiv\left(\pdv{}{x},\pdv{}{y},\pdv{}{z}\right)$$
But writing
$$\nabla=\left(\pdv{}{z},\pdv{}{y},\pdv{}{x}\right)\equiv\pdv{}{z}\mathbf{\hat x}+\pdv{}{y}\mathbf{\hat y}+\pdv{}{x}\mathbf{\hat z}$$
doesn't make sense.

Hope this helps. :)